# Error when taking a screenshot of a very large window

Tags: macos, screenshot, large-files, macos-catalina

I am using IDLE for Python on Mac (Catalina 10.15.7) and I would like to be able to take a screenshot (Command + Shift + 4 + Space + Enter) of the preview window for function inputs, shown here:

[image]

This usually works, but if the preview window is very large, the command returns an error, "Your screenshot can't be saved. Unable to capture window image.":

[image]

Here is an example of a large window (1298x16094) that I could take a screenshot of:

(Error displaying, I'll try to fix shortly)
[image]

I am wondering if this is some sort of intentional limitation, or perhaps a flaw in the screenshot program, but I have not been able to find anyone online with the same problem, and I have also been unable to find a way to directly access the code for screenshots. When displaying these large windows, IDLE does jump up in memory usage by as much as a few hundred MB, but I don't see why this would necessarily prevent saving a screenshot.

I have not tried using any third party software, though I would prefer to avoid this if possible.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: This probably is better suited for https://apple.stackexchange.com or Apple’s forums. This is a general macOS question, not directly related a programming, and is therefore is not [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for this forum.

Comment: Ah ok, I can try posting there, though I was also hoping there may be some kind of command line or coding solution to this problem. For example, if I could find where the code is, perhaps I could try to alter it for my purposes.

Comment: FWIW, 1298×16094 requires an exceptionally large pixel buffer. Ignore JPG/PNG sizes (those are compressed file formats), but consider that it likely has to process the original uncompressed pixel buffer; 4 bytes/pixel for a total of 80mb, at least. I could easily imagine either a conscious limitation having been imposed, or just some general memory related issue during the capture/processing. Despite your reticence, I might suggest you reconsider third-party solutions. I like CleanShot X (but have no idea what the max size it handles), but there are quite a few alternatives out there.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll look into CleanShot X

Comment: Out of curiosity, did that handle the huge images more gracefully?

Comment: I decided not to try it as there was no free trial. I did see in the comments of a video it had trouble with scrolling capture of a large image, so I wouldn't be surprised if it has similar limitations for large window capture.